# Display Sparklines in a table in lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, aura, aura-attribute

How can I display sparklines based on my data inside table for each row dynamically in lightning Components.
I have tried to display them but sparklines are not displaying in my table last column.
There are two static resources we have used 1.jquery, 2.jquery sparklines
here is the link for jquery sparklines  [JQuery Sparklines](https://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-about)
Can anyone suggest solution for it.

Here is my Component code:

```
   <aura:component controller="Testing" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
   <aura:handler name="init"  value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:attribute name="mycolumn" type="Object[]"/>
     <aura:attribute name="Records" type="Object" />
    <aura:attribute name="selectedtype" type="String" />  
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="Executioncount" type="Integer" />
    <lightning:card > 
          <ltng:require scripts="{!join(',', $Resource.jq, $Resource.JQSP)}"  />
   
          <div class="slds-size_1-of-8 slds-align_right" style="margin-left = 10px; padding-left: 20px " >            
            <lightning:select aura:id="invoice" name="select" label="Subscription started in Last" value="{!v.selectedtype}" onchange="{!c.doInit}" >                          
                
                <option value="30">30 days</option>
                <option value="60">60 days</option> 
                <option value="90">90 days</option>
                <option value="180">180 days</option> 
            </lightning:select>      
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
          <div style="padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; width: 100%;align:center">          
                <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered" aura:id="tid" >
                    <thead >
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" style = "width:10%;background-color:#ededed;font-size: 14px;">Install Date</th>
                            <th scope="col" style = "width:10%;background-color:#ededed;font-size:14px;text-align:right">SignUp Date</th>           
                            <th scope="col" style = "width:15%;background-color:#ededed;font-size: 14px;text-align:right">Invoice Tier</th>
                            <th scope="col" style = "width:15%;background-color:#ededed;font-size:14px;text-align:right">Average Invoices</th>
                            <th scope="col" style = "width:15%;background-color:#ededed;font-size:14px;text-align:right">Chart</th>
                                           
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.Records.licenseList}" var="eachRecord" >
                                <tr class="slds-hint-parent" id="ff">
                                    <td data-label="{!eachRecord}">{!eachRecord.sfLma__Install_Date__c}</td>
                                     <td data-label="{!eachRecord}" style="text-align:right">{!eachRecord.Signup_Date__c}</td>
                                   <td data-label="{!eachRecord}" style="text-align:right;width=300px"><lightning:formattedNumber value="{!eachRecord.BW_Invoice_Tier__c}" maximumFractionDigits="2" style="currency"/></td>
                                    <td data-label="{!eachRecord}" style="text-align:right;width=300px">{!eachRecord.BW_Average_Invoices__c}</td>
                                    <td > 
                                     
                                    </td>
                                </tr>                                
                       </aura:iteration>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div> 
         
    </lightning:card>   
    </aura:component>
```

Here is my controller.js

```
 ({
     doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        
 
     var returnedObj=[];
          var selectType=event.getSource().get("v.value");
         console.log(selectType);
         if(selectType==undefined)
             selectType="30";
         console.log("Changed value is "+selectType);
       var action=component.get("c.customerLicenseDetails");
          action.setParams({"selectedType": selectType});
            action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
          
            component.set("v.Records",response.getReturnValue());
                returnedObj=(response.getReturnValue());
                console.log(returnedObj);
         component.find('tid').set("v.value", null);   
         var table=component.find('tid').getElement();
                console.log('This is table'+table);
                var tableArr = [];
                var tableLab = [];
                console.log('This no of rows for a given table '+table.rows.length);
      for ( var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++ ) {
          
tableArr.push([
     table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML,
     table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML,
     table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML
     
    ]);
tableLab.push(table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML);
          var div = document.createElement("div");
console.log('This is canv '+div);
          div.setAttribute("id", "myChart"+i);
        table.rows[i].cells[4].appendChild(div);
}
tableArr.forEach(function(e,i){
    console.log(returnedObj["ActionList"][i]);
                $("#myChart"+(i+1)).sparkline(returnedObj["ActionList"][i], {
    type: 'line',
     lineColor:'#006dcc',                               
    width: '100px',
    height: '24px',
    lineWidth: 0.6,
    fillColor: 'white',                                
    spotColor: '#f08000 ',
    minSpotColor: '#ff7f00',
    spotRadius: 0,
    normalRangeMax: 1,
    normalRangeColor: '#c0c0c0',
    drawNormalOnTop:true,
                          tooltipFormat: '{{offset:offset}} :<b> {{y:val}}</b> ',
    tooltipValueLookups: {
        'offset': returnedObj["DatesList"][i]
           
    },  
                      });

});
                

                           });   
            
             
    
         
          
        
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
       
    }
   
    
})
```

Here is picture of my output:

[image]

Comment: Use your browser's "Developer Tools" to see any JavaScript errors. You can also set breakpoints and examine data values.

Comment: I have checked my console  it is not showing any errors but not getting output

Comment: Likely the way you are finding the elements. See e.g. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_ids.htm. I recollect sometimes finding by class instead so normal jQuery selectors can be used.